# Where to get PAM auth DLL for win64

Tags: windows-7, python3, pam

My python pack (Python-pam package) needs PAM auth lib DLL.

```
    libpam=CDLL(find_library("pam"))
libc=CDLL(find_library("c"))
```

Where to get those dlls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't. Windows does not use PAM for authentication.